# Changing the function of laptop buttons?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10-upgrade, button-remapping

On my laptop, above the keyboard, there are two buttons, one for toggling the wifi, the other for toggling the bluetooth.

Since I have installed the Windows 10 update the function of these buttons has changed.

The wifi button now toggles flight mode, and the bluetooth button now opens a new Chrome Window!

I can't work out where/how to change the function of these buttons back to what they were before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:

Manufacturer:     Hewlett-Packard

Model:            HP ProBook 4740s

Comment: Since buttons outside the standard keyboard and keypad are highly manufacturer and model specific, it would help if you edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Those buttons are controlled by software specific to the laptop manufacturer. Check for updates to that software.

Answer (score 0):

Install the hotkey support driver, its under "Driver - Keyboard, Mouse and Input Devices (4)" section

Your driver support page for Windows 10

http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5229499&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4192